# Laravel 5.5 + Vue.js 2.x Proper API requests

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am working locally on a Laravel 5.5 project which uses Vue.js 2.5.9 on with XAMP Server.

I have to load some information to the DOM and refresh it when click "Refresh" button.

Sometimes the information is loaded and well displayed but sometimes they are not (some of the responses are):

> **Error 429:** { "message": "Too Many Attempts." }
>
> **Error 500:** { "message": "Server Error." }

I managed to "solve" the first issue (*error 429*) by increasing the Middleware throttle in **Kernel.php** from `'throttle:60,1',` to `100,1`)

But the second error I am not sure why I am get it sometimes and sometimes not.

I have this in my **APIController** (for example):

```
public function users()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return response()->json($users);
}
```

Then in **app.js** I call the methods in the created hook like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ...
        totalUsers: 0,
        ...
    },
    created: function() {
        ...
        this.loadUsers();
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        loadUsers: function() {
        axios.get('/api/admin/users')
            .then(function (response) {
                app.totalUsers = response.data.length;
            });
        },
        refreshData: function() {
            this.loadUsers():
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

Maybe should I replace `$users = User::all()` to `$users = User::count()` to avoid loading "too much data" in API requests?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should be using `mounted()` instead of `created()` in your vue.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ...
        totalUsers: 0,
        ...
    },
    mounted: function() {
        ...
        this.loadUsers();
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        loadUsers: function() {
        axios.get('/api/admin/users')
            .then(function (response) {
                app.totalUsers = response.data.length;
            });
        },
        refreshData: function() {
            this.loadUsers():
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

that's the equivalent of the `$(document).on(ready)` in jQuery.  Thats the method that fires when the window has fully loaded.

On a side note, Laravel knows when it is returning json as an ajax response, so you could probably just amend you controller method to this

```
public function users()
{
    return User::all();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will change from created to mounted and already changed the method retrieves. It worked.

Comment: `mounted` has nothing to do with whether the document is loaded or not. It fires when the *component* or root Vue's DOM has been added to the DOM.